# Is it okay to connect all links of a node in a function create_new_node?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am learning linked list and I am just wondering if it is good/ bad practice to connect all links of a new node with the function *create_new.

From what i read online, they only the next link, but i want to make it connect the previous link as well. Here is my code:

```
node *create_new (int new_data, node *prev, node *next)
{
node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
if (new_node == NULL)
{
    printf("Error in creating new node\n");
    exit(0);
}

new_node->data = new_data;
new_node->next = next;
prev->next = new_node;

return new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works. However, for a singly linked list you do not need to pass `next` because `prev->next` should point at `next`:

```
node *create_new (int new_data, node *prev)
{
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in creating new node\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = prev->next;
    prev->next = new_node;

    return new_node;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah thks for this, just realised it. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

That allows to insert a cell into a doubled linked list (like std::list) or replace consecutive cells by a new one

If *prev->next* is *next* you to insert the new cell between them.

If *prev->next* is not *next* all the cells between them are replaced by the new one (and may be lost and not deleted)

If you have `n0<->n2<->n3` and you do `create_new(1, n0, n2)` you will have `n0<->n1<->n2<->n3` but if now you do `create_new(7, n0, n3)` you will have `n0<->n7<>n3` and the cells *n1* and *n2* are removed (and may be lost)

So one thing is sure : it is wrongly named because it is more *replaceBetween*

Comment: thks for the response. Because in all 3 websites that i read, they didn't connect the previous link in their function but rather manually connect it later in another function like inserting node at the beginning or at the end. So i thought might as well follow the tradition.

Comment: what if i still keep my function and pass NULL as prev when the list is empty (create the first node)? Will that work?

Comment: @ThomasD in your current definition you do `prev->next = new_node;` so you will have a problem with a NULL pointer, so for that case you need to check _prev_

Comment: In that case, should i stick to the original (not making the prev->next link to new_node) since this does not apply when you add new node to an empty list but rather, as you said, add between nodes of an existed list?

Comment: @ThomasD all depends on what to want to propose, but you need to also propose additional functions helping to make the list, and as I say in my answer you need to rename the current function because it is not a simple _create_

Answer (score 1):

- A simple linked list's node has a pointer to the next node only.
- A double linked list's node has two pointers; a pointer to the next node  and a pointer to the previous node.

I assume you read online about simple linked lists (by default when people talk about linked lists, they are the simple ones).